# How do I vectorize a Pandas function that counts rows belonging to a group and falling between two dates?

Tags: python, pandas, vectorization

I have the following table and I want to count the number of active jobs, per client, on each day in 2020. A job is active if the date falls on or between its start_date and end_date.

| job | client | start_date | end_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AA001 | ALPHA | 2020/12/19 | 2020/12/28 |
| AA002 | ALPHA | 2020/04/03 | 2020/10/10 |
| AA003 | BRAVO | 2020/10/11 | 2020/10/11 |
| AA004 | CHARLIE | 2020/04/06 | 2020/11/15 |
| AA005 | ALPHA | 2020/04/01 | 2020/04/30 |
| AA006 | CHARLIE | 2020/05/01 | 2020/06/03 |
| AA007 | BRAVO | 2020/06/04 | 2020/06/17 |
| AA008 | BRAVO | 2020/06/18 | 2020/07/01 |
| AA009 | CHARLIE | 2020/07/02 | 2020/08/04 |
| AA010 | ALPHA | 2020/05/05 | 2020/08/06 |
| AA011 | BRAVO | 2020/10/12 | 2020/11/04 |

For instance, here is how many jobs were active for client ALPHA at the beginning of April:

| Date | Client | Active jobs |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ALPHA | 2020-04-01 | 1 |
| ALPHA | 2020-04-02 | 1 |
| ALPHA | 2020-04-03 | 2 |
| ALPHA | 2020-04-04 | 2 |
| ALPHA | 2020-04-05 | 2 |
| ALPHA | 2020-04-06 | 2 |
| ALPHA | 2020-04-07 | 2 |
| ALPHA | 2020-04-08 | 2 |
| ALPHA | 2020-04-09 | 2 |
| ALPHA | 2020-04-10 | 2 |

I can solve this problem using nested loops, e.g.

```
groups = df.groupby(["client"])   
dates = pd.date_range('2020-01-01','2020-12-01', freq='D')   
 
for client, jobs in groups:  
    for date in dates:  
        active_jobs = jobs.loc[(jobs.start_date <= date) & (jobs.end_date >= date)]  
        print(date,client,len(active_jobs))
```

(Explanation: group rows by client, construct a list of dates, then for each date for each client, find/count the rows where start_date <= date and end_date >= date.)

Of course my real data is much larger than this and looping is very inefficient. How do I rewrite my query to take advantage of vectorization?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Approach with broadcasting

Check for the inclusion of `dates` between the `start_date` and `end_date` columns, this will create a boolean mask, now we create a new dataframe from this mask and assign the column names to the corresponding dates, then `group` this dataframe by `client` and aggregate using `sum` to count the number of active jobs for each client on each day

```
start, end = df[['start_date', 'end_date']].to_numpy().T
dates = pd.date_range('2020-01-01','2020-12-01', freq='D').to_numpy()

m = (start[:, None] <= dates) & (end[:, None] >= dates)
s = pd.DataFrame(m, columns=dates).groupby(df['client']).sum().stack()
```

After stacking the resulting series containing the counts of `active_jobs` will look like

```
>>> s

client             
ALPHA    2020-01-01    0
         2020-01-02    0
         2020-01-03    0
         2020-01-04    0
         2020-01-05    0
                      ..
CHARLIE  2020-11-27    0
         2020-11-28    0
         2020-11-29    0
         2020-11-30    0
         2020-12-01    0
Length: 1008, dtype: int64
```

Examining the active jobs for client `ALPHA` for the month of `APRIL`

```
>>> s.loc[pd.IndexSlice['ALPHA', '2020-04-01':]]

client            
ALPHA   2020-04-01    1
        2020-04-02    1
        2020-04-03    2
        2020-04-04    2
        2020-04-05    2
        2020-04-06    2
        2020-04-07    2
        2020-04-08    2
        2020-04-09    2
        2020-04-10    2
        2020-04-11    2
        2020-04-12    2
        2020-04-13    2
        2020-04-14    2
        2020-04-15    2
        2020-04-16    2
        2020-04-17    2
        2020-04-18    2
        2020-04-19    2
        2020-04-20    2
        2020-04-21    2
        2020-04-22    2
        2020-04-23    2
        2020-04-24    2
        2020-04-25    2
        2020-04-26    2
        2020-04-27    2
        2020-04-28    2
        2020-04-29    2
        2020-04-30    2
dtype: int64
```

PS: Although using broadcasting is faster but it will require sufficient amount of memory to hold the intermediate boolean mask in memory. One more thing you also have to convert the `start_date` and `end_date` column to pandas `datetime` format prior to using this approach

Comment: which one is the broadcasting step here? Is it the variable 's'?

Comment: @RamanSrinivasan The creating of boolean mask `m` is the broadcasting step here.

Comment: @RamanSrinivasan Thank you, this is approximately 10,000 times faster